# How can I loop through only .cpp files in the list obtained from "git status"

Tags: bash, git, shell, pre-commit-hook

I have a tool to analyse every .cpp file. I am implementing a pre-commit hook to analyse only edited and staged .cpp files in the local git repository before committing the changes. I have a shell script that gets called from the pre-commit hook and currently my following code fails to fetch me changed .cpp files. What is wrong with this script?

Code:

```
files=$(git status --porcelain | cut -b4-)
for file in $files; do
    if [$file == *.cpp]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Error:

```
./build_script.sh: line 23: [build_script.sh: command not found
./build_script.sh: line 23: [pre_commit_sqo_tmp/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: the old style `[` command is literally a *command*. It's also known as `test` (`/bin/test`): `if test x = y; then ...; fi`. When invoked as the `[` command, it demands a closing `]`, so that's why the syntax is `if [ x = y ]; then ...; fi`, with required white-space: we want to run `/bin/[` and provide, as arguments, `x` `=` `y` `]` in that order. Using the bash `[[` built-in is more convenient here though.

Comment: It's not any *faster* as bash and other modern shells have `test` aka `[` built in as well (as long as you invoke them by simple name and not full `/bin/test` etc path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add spaces and use `[[`:

```
if [[ $file == *.cpp ]]; then
```

See [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for the difference between `[` and `[[`.

Also you can use

```
git ls-files -m "*.cpp"
```

This lists modified files with the given pattern. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files . Please note the quotes — the pattern is screened to avoid the shell to interpret it; the pattern is passed to Git.